# Problem with activerecord find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 5 tables and they related between. Everythings good, perfectly! But i tried to make script, than if in inquiry table field is_answered = 0, so i find respondents (by respondent_id in question table) and send them letter
BUT 
I HAVE MISTAKE!

I have this code:

```
inquiry       = Inquiry.find(:all, :conditions => ["is_answered = 0"])
question      = inquiry.question 
respondents   = Respondent.find(:all, :conditions => ["id = (?)", question.user_id])

respondents.each do |r|
  Notifier.deliver_user_notification(inquiry)
end
```

And when i typing `ruby blah.rb` i get this error:

```
undefined method `question' for #<Array:0x7f646c82b568>
```

What my mistake?

PS - `Inquiry` table (`id, question_id, respondent_i`d) relationship table between `questions` and `answers`.
PSS - `Respondent table` related with `Inquiry`.

Comment: `inquiry = Inquiry.find(:all, [...])` gives you a collection (as an array) of inquiries not just one. You can't call `inquiry.question` on the array. Try your code in the console and you'll see.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you have more inquiry so the following returns an array.

```
Inquiry.find(:all, :conditions => ["is_answered = 0"])
```

Try the following, but be mindful of how many sql queries it does, as there are probably optimisations that can be made:

```
inquiry       = Inquiry.find(:all, :conditions => ["is_answered = 0"])
inquiry.each do |i|
    question      = i.question
    respondents   = Respondent.find(:all, :conditions => ["id = (?)", question.user_id])

    respondents.each do |r|
      Notifier.deliver_user_notification(inquiry)
    end
end
```